# react native toolbar android with dropdown like, for example, whatsapp

Tags: react-native, android-toolbar, whatsapp

i need develop a dropdown like, for example, whatsapp.

This is my code trying to do it with ToolbarAndroid

```
<Icon.ToolbarAndroid
              titleColor={'#000000'}
              style={{
                 height: 56,
                 alignSelf: 'stretch',
                 width: 20
               }}
              iconColor={"#fff"}
              iconSize={26}
              rtl={true}
              navIconName={"more-vert"}
              contentInsetStart={50}
              actions={[{title: 'Settings', show: 'always'}, {title: 'Settings 2', show: 'always'}]} />
```

I dont know if ToolbarAndroid is the component what i need, maybe if i know the real name of this style of menu i can be more accurate in google searchs.

Here an image of the menu:

[I need do a menu like this (whatsapp)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uQt9.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change it here:

```
actions={[{title: 'Settings', show: 'never'}, {title: 'Settings 2', show: 'never'}]} />
```

This is called overflow menu in android:

Action **"Show:"**

> when to show this action as an icon or hide it in the overflow menu:
>   **always, ifRoom or never**

if you set never, it will hide in overflow menu icon at the right side of toolbar.

For more information see this [ToolbarAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html)